# Embedded Script tags in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags, fwrite

I have a basic template builder that I wrote using PHP with `fwrite`. As part of the function I store the script tags to be embedded within a variable like so:

```
$script='<script type="application/javascript" src="' . $src . '"></script>'
```

Then I write that variable at the appropriate place in an html fragment inside of a HEREDOC string.  And it's not working.  It outputs commented tags into the produced html file.

However, the following works as expected:

```
$script='script type="application/javascript src="' . $src . '"></script';
```

and then in the HEREDOC string like so:

```
<$script>
```

---

So fine...a workaround.  Whatever...  **But the thing that's weird to me** is that Sublime Text shows the first code as a syntax error.   Doesn't say what the error is; just shows a white dot.  And appropriately the output doesn't work.

Running `php -l` reveals no errors.  But the fact that Sublime catches it (and it is obvious after several times rearranging code that what the error is referring to really is the fact that I have a `script` tag inside a variable) - leads me to believe that this is expected behavior.  I can't find anything documented about this though.  And the workaround I came up with is so lame that it's hard for me to imagine that that's all it would take to circumvent what I can only imagine to be a security restriction.

Do I have an error somewhere else that I'm missing?  Or is this just how it is?

Comment: it reads like an error with sublime (not that i know what *sublime* is).

Comment: It's a code editor.  Not known for making errors.

Comment: first time for everything

Comment: indeed....It's Sublime Text.  Check it out.  It is an extremely satisfactory code edit editor cross platform.